# How to disable all buttons on the page while uploading?

Tags: jquery, button

I'm using json +jquery on client side. I want to disable all buttons found on the page while uploading file. Currently I'm disabling the upload button only using its id as shown below..

> ```
> $("#upload_attachment_button").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
> ```

I wonder if there is a way to disable the rest of the buttons found on the page. I have done a function that I want to use by all the system, and I don't want to send the buttons id every time I want to call this function..

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's rather simple. Select all the input elements of the form with type button and disable them:

```
$("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: so if I want to enable them again, I should do something like this: `$("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", "enabled");` or what, cause this did not work with me.

Comment: I used `$("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", false);` and `$("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", true);`

Comment: You should use $("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");