# Disable all buttons on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC view with a number of buttons on it (each item in a basket renders 2 buttons)...

```
<button class="pbbg" id="ProductMinus_161637" type="button">-</button>
<button class="pbbg" id="ProductPlus_161637" type="button">+</button>
```

(they both have an `onclick` event)

When either of these buttons are pressed I want to disable all the buttons for every product until the basket has finished updating.

The click event calls a JavaScript function which in turn makes an Ajax call.  Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822054/how-to-disable-all-buttons-on-the-page-while-uploading) the first thing I try to do is disable all the buttons.....

```
$("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Then after the Ajax call returns reenable them....

```
$("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");
```

I am getting no errors but the buttons are not disabled.

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Try using prop $("input[type=button]").prop("disabled", true);

Comment: Your elements are not `inputs` (they are buttons!) - change your html to `<input type="button" ... />` (and use `.prop('disabled', true)`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Doh! Thanks I didn't spot that.  Took the html straight from the designer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. instead of `input..` selector you should use `:button` pseudo-selector.

You can use `:button` selector to select all the buttons.

```
$(':button').prop('disabled', true); // Disable all the buttons
```

To enable all the buttons:

```
$(':button').prop('disabled', false); // Enable all the button
```

**EDIT**

If you want to disable only the buttons whose id starts with `Product` use:

```
$('button[id^="Product"]')
```

Comment: What is the point of using the `:button` pseudo-selector vs `"button"`, and of using `prop` over `attr`?

Comment: `:button` will select all the `button`, `input[type="button"]` and `input[type="submit"]`

Comment: what about hidden buttons, these solutions do not change hidden buttons.

Answer (score 6):

If anybody is looking for a vanilla javascript solution:

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (const button of buttons) {
  button.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you're not using the `input` tag, you're using the straight `button` tag. Try `$("button").attr("disabled", "disable")` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `button` selector. Try `prop` like this

```
$('button').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla JavaScript solution:**

```js
// Disable all buttons
const allBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button')
allBtn.forEach((button) => {
  button.disabled = true;
});
```

Comment: Why use `forEach` instead of `for..of` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73635866/?

Answer (score -1):

if you want try this .

const buttons = document.getElementById("button");
buttons.setAttribute('disabled', true);

Comment: `getElementById` returns one element.  The question is for disabling **all** elements of the button type.